# How to capture the motion event when touch move from view group to child view?

Tags: android, view, touch-event

I write a custom view group to implement functions what i want. But i have a problem need your help. 
The problem is : the finger move from view group to the child view. But i miss the touch event when the finger on the child view.
I override the view group's ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent and ViewGroup.onTouchEventmethod. I fond that when the view group's ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvnet return true, the view group's ViewGroup.onTouchEvent will handle the motion event. and then the motion events will post to the view group's ViewGroup.onTouchEvent, will not pass the view group's ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent method. when the finger move from view group to the child view, the motion event will pass to the view group's ViewGroup.onTouchEvent directly , I can not dispatch the motion event to the child view. wait for your help. please!

```
This is the Layout :

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/str_textview_title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <com.example.pullrefreshlayout.PullRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_pull_refresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_title" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </com.example.pullrefreshlayout.PullRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

This is my ViewGroup , it's a PullRefreshLayou.


@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent action is: " + ev.getAction());

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mTouchEventY = ev.getY();
            mTouchEventX = ev.getX();

            if (mHeaderView.getBottom() <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (mState == STATE_REFRESHING) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            double moveDistanceY = ev.getY() - mTouchEventY;
            double moveDistanceX = ev.getX() - mTouchEventX;

            mTouchEventX = ev.getX();
            mTouchEventY = ev.getY();

            if (Math.abs(moveDistanceY) < 2 * Math.abs(moveDistanceX)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "moveDistanceY < 2 * moveDistanceX");
                return false;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "move distance is :" + moveDistanceY);
            if (isRefreshReady() && moveDistanceY > 3) {
                // 判断ContentView在顶部，而且有下拉的操作，moveDistance还可调大
                return true;
            }

            if (mHeaderView.getBottom() <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent action is :" + event.getAction());

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            int moveDistance = (int) (event.getY() - mTouchEventY);
            Log.i(TAG, "move distance is :" + moveDistance);

            if (moveDistance < 0) {
                moveDistance = moveDistance > -mHeaderView.getBottom() ? moveDistance
                        : -mHeaderView.getBottom();
            }

            mHeaderView.offsetTopAndBottom(moveDistance);
            mContentView.offsetTopAndBottom(moveDistance);
            invalidate();

            int headerViewTop = mHeaderView.getTop();
            if (headerViewTop >= 0 && mHeaderViewTop < 0
                    && mState != STATE_REFRESHING) {
                mHeaderView.startUpAnimation();
                mHeaderView.onReleaseToRefresh(mRefreshTime);
                mState = STATE_RELEASE_TO_REFRESH;
            }

            if (headerViewTop < 0 && mHeaderViewTop >= 0
                    && mState != STATE_REFRESHING) {
                mHeaderView.startDownAnimation();
                mHeaderView.onPullToRefresh(mRefreshTime);
                mState = STATE_PULL_TO_REFRESH;
            }

            mHeaderViewTop = headerViewTop;

            mTouchEventY = event.getY();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if (mHeaderView.getTop() >= 0) {
                // 刷新
                if (mState != STATE_REFRESHING) {
                    if (null != mPullRefreshListener) {
                        mPullRefreshListener.onRefresh();
                    }
                    mState = STATE_REFRESHING;
                    mHeaderView.onRefresh(mRefreshTime);
                }

                scrollToRefresh();

            } else {
                // 不刷新
                if (mHeaderView.getTop() > -mHeaderViewHeight
                        && mState != STATE_REFRESHING) {
                    mState = STATE_DEFAULT;
                    scrollToClose();
                }
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

         return false;
    }

OK.
```

Comment: What exaclly are you trying. to do?

Comment: It is a pull to refresh layout.